# Swapping out elements between ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist, swap

I have 2 ArrayList that I need to swap out the elements between the two from a certain starting point.

My current code looks something like this:

```
    List<Character> seq1 = new ArrayList<Character>(someArrayList);
    List<Character> seq2 = new ArrayList<Character>(someArrayList);
    List<Character> tmp1 = new ArrayList<Character>(someArrayList);
    List<Character> tmp2 = new ArrayList<Character>(someArrayList);

        for(int i = start1; i <= seq1.size()-1; i++){
            tmp1.set(i,seq2.get(i));
        }
        for(int i = start2; i <= seq2.size()-1; i++){
            tmp2.set(i,seq1.get(i));
        }
        for(int i = start1; i <= seq1.size()-1; i++){
            tmp1.set(i,seq2.get(i));
        }
        for(int i = start2; i <= seq2.size()-1; i++){
            tmp2.set(i,seq1.get(i));
        }
```

Assuming `start1`, and `start2` are both 4

For instance:

```
seq1: {A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B}

seq2: {A,A,A,A,C,C,C,C}
```

The end result should be:

```
seq1:{A,A,A,A,C,C,C,C}

seq2:{A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B}
```

But mine still seem to be returning with their original values.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: instead of iteration why don't you add all  list to `seq1 ->tmp1 ,seq2-> tmp2` do clear list and swap the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of collection you will not need any temporary swapping variable or other thing. Just replace the values.

```
for(int i = start1, j = start2; i < seq1.size() && j < seq2.size(); i++, j++){
    seq1.set(i, seq2.set(j, seq1.get(i)));
}
```

Comment: I think I will give you the 'correct answer' because you aren't wrong for what I was asking. Using your for loop and suggestions, my issue was my unit test was not testing these declared array lists since seq1,and seq2, had NEW instead of the actual references, and therefore were not the ones being unit tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Character> seq1 = new ArrayList<Character>();
    List<Character> seq2 = new ArrayList<Character>();
    seq1.add('A');
    seq1.add('B');
    seq1.add('B');

    seq2.add('A');
    seq2.add('C');
    seq2.add('C');
    List<Character> tmp1 = new ArrayList<Character>(seq1);
    List<Character> tmp2 = new ArrayList<Character>(seq2);

        int start1 = 1, start2 = 1;
        for(int i = start1; i <= seq1.size()-1; i++){
            tmp1.set(i,seq2.get(i));
        }
        for(int i = start2; i <= seq2.size()-1; i++){
            tmp2.set(i,seq1.get(i));
        }

   System.out.println(tmp1.toString());     
}
```

It works.

The problem is you are modifying `list tmp1 and tmp2`. So content gets modified in temp lists.

And It seems you are trying to print original list which was not modified by your code